# Error when trying to backup Gitlab

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab

When I'm trying to backup my instance of Gitlab on my server with the command

```
gitlab-ci-rake backup:create
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/gitlab-ci-rake error: could not load /opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-ci/gitlab-ci-rc
Either you are not allowed to read the file, or it does not exist yet.
You can generate it with:   sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

So I tried the `reconfigure` command with no changes.

Does anybody have an idea how I could fix this problem? Or is there an other way to do backups without this command?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem, when I backup as root and show this error.

So I change the login as another user (not root) and successfully backup

Comment: Unfortunately the error still appears, when I try as another user (with sudo access).

Comment: are you using gitlab-ce or gitlab-ci ?

have you try this command : sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create

Comment: This command worked. Thank you very much. Can you maybe explain, what's the difference between the command I tried and this one?